# .exe in artoolkit bin folder not executing and says applpication failed to start correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, artoolkit

After building the artoolkit.sln in the visual studio and when examples like simpletest1 is made to run the error pops out saying 'Failed to start the application ' .. 
  Help regarding is really appreciated

Thanks in advance
Ankith

Answer (score 0):

When you install the ARToolkit (i.e extracting the ZIP distribution), All the files are extracted only with Read and Write permissions, but not with execute permissions.

Hence change the permission to Read,Write & Execute (i.e. 777, 755, etc) and then try to run the file. It might run.